# Remove battery panel on Yamaha Cygnus 125 2010

Tags: battery, yamaha, scooter

I have a Yamaha Cygnus 125 bought in 2010. I need to recharge / change the battery, but I am unable to remove the cover panel.

The battery is situated in the back, under the seat. The panel got two screws, but they seem to turn without moving. I have also tried to force the panel open with a lever, but it seems to be blocked.

The manual just say "open the panel".

Is there an unusual / unintuitive way to open that panel?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: the plastic screws are really delicate and they do not turn with enough accuracy to really unlock the panel. The only way I have found is to insert a lever and pull harder, and the panel comes out without breaking anything.